# Pass by pointer reference with stack push

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, stack

My node definition for the stack I am trying to create:

```
typedef struct node {
double value;
struct node *prev;
} node_t;
```

In main:

```
node_t *stack = NULL;
push(stack, new_node(strtod(token, NULL)));
```

Note about new_node function - with token = "1", new_node returns a node with struct node *prev equal to NULL (as desired) with double value = 1 (as desired)

```
 void push(node_t *stack, node_t node) {
    if(stack != NULL) {
        node_t temp;
        temp = stack[0];
        stack = &node;
        node.prev = &temp;
    }
    else {
        stack = &node;
    }
}
```

When I modify stack, I am expecting stack to be modified in main as well; however, this is not the case. In main, after push() is called, the stack remains NULL.

Comment: You will need to post the new_node() code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
node_t *stack = NULL;
push(stack, new_node(strtod(token, NULL)));
```

You create a pointer, pass it **by value** to a function, and then expect it to be changed afterward.  But C doesn't work like that--variables passed by value are not modified in the calling context.  You need to pass a pointer (to the pointer) instead:

```
node_t *stack = NULL;
push(&stack, new_node(strtod(token, NULL)));
```

Then:

```
 void push(node_t **stack, node_t node) {
    if(*stack != NULL) {
        node_t temp;
        temp = (*stack)[0];
        *stack = &node;
        node.prev = &temp;
    }
    else {
        *stack = &node;
    }
}
```

Now the changes will be visible outside, because you use the double-pointer to modify the pointer.